# XSL Display error based on error code

Tags: xslt

I have an XML document that contains multiple pre-defined error message that has a structure similar to this

```
<main>
   <error>
      <code1>message</code1>
      <code2>message</code2>
   </error>
<main>
```

Certain operations can return errors and the error code is added in the request so that the error is displayed on the page:
_request.setAttribute("errorCode", errorCode);

In the XSL document I have a structure like this:

```
<xsl:if test="root/request/error">
    <div class="grid_16 errors">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/root/main/error/', root/request/errorCode)"/>
    </div>
</xsl:if>
```

The error code is placed in the request like this:

```
_request.setAttribute("error", "true");
_request.setAttribute("errorCode", errorCode.get());
```

However, the error is not displayed, but instead the result of the concatenation (the string `/root/main/error/code1`). If I put, for example, one error code like this, it works: `<xsl:value-of select="/root/main/error/code1"/>`

Is there a way to properly display the error by providing the just the code?

Comment: There are couple of discrepancies in the samples provided. The input XML does not have any element `errorCode` which you are trying to access in XSL. The `<xsl:value-of>` will try to print `/root/main/error/xxxx` based on what XPath resolves for the `root/request/error/root/request/errorCode`. I think you need to just do a `value-of select="errorCode"` since you are already in the `error` context according to the condition in `<xsl:if>`.

Comment: I updated the example. The error code send in the request is just 'code1'.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/main/error/*[name()=/root/request/errorCode]" />
```